# How to log all HTTP requests to site, using Yii Framework?

Tags: php, logging, yii, httprequest

I want to log all HTTP requests to site, framework Yii.

Can i use standard capabilities of framework?

Comment: I know this article, but i cant find how to log http requests, only errors. I dont want to write custom code in framework code

Comment: If you just want a log of HTTP Requests and you're running Apache as your server, you can just use the Access Log that already exists: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#accesslog. Or, is there a specific need to do this inside Yii?

Comment: yes, i know about Apache logs, but i thought that Yii suggest similar functionality

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  And *why*?  *Why* do you want the *application* to log requests, when the server already does this for you?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Apache logs will include all the extras that don't pass through Yii - CSS, JS, images...

Comment: I need to see all requests and all POST parameters, but Apache log only requests without params

Comment: But Apache does not record the logined user in the access log!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've done it using `onBeginRequest` or `onEndRequest`.  See more info here: [How to use events in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410045/how-to-use-events-in-yii)

In essence, you hook the global request event with a class of your own and then do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

In [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/) the events are called `beforeRequest` and `afterRequest` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html)

For example:

```
Yii::$app->on('afterRequest', function($event) {
    //do something...
    //response object is in $event->sender->response
    //response data is in $event->sender->response->data
    //request object is in $event->sender->request
});
```

But this is before *response data* has been prepared into *response content* (according to *response format*, eg. `Response::FORMAT_JSON`) so if you want the true final response body you need to do this (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#sending-response):

```
Yii::$app->response->on(\yii\web\Response::EVENT_AFTER_SEND, function($event) {  //alternatively use EVENT_AFTER_PREPARE
    //now you can access $event->sender->content and eg. $event->sender->getHeaders()
    //Also, you have access to the request through Yii::$app->request
});
```