# Yii load system params from Database using Active Record

Tags: yii

I am interested in loading some system params into the `Yii::app()->params` array from the database using a `CActiveRecord` extension called `SiteSetting`.

Unfortunately I couldn't find much advice online for this, but believe I can place a method in `SiteSetting` called `loadSiteSettingsToAppParams` and add the setting...

```
'onBeginRequest'=>array('SiteSetting', 'loadSiteSettingsToAppParams')
```

...to the config.

I would like to know if I can only add this `onBeginRequest` to the `Yii::app()` somewhere within the `SiteSetting` class (to keep my code modular) and whether this is a sensible approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can lookup an answer to your question " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410045/how-to-use-events-in-yii "

Comment: Thanks, but I read that article prior to posting and it doesn't actually answer my question. Good link though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-read your question now and I'd try to provide answers.

To the question "I would like to know if I can only add this `onBeginRequest` to the `Yii::app()` somewhere within the `SiteSetting` class (to keep my code modular)": the answer is, You're not restricted to just a Class. You could (theoretically) place it anywhere within your application and also in the `config.php` file.

As to whether it's a sensible approach, it depends on the time it would take to request those settings from the database and whether you're prepared to add that time to your HttpRequest response time. The `onBeforeRequest` is fired before every HttpRequest and if the `loadSiteSettingsToAppParams` method consumes lots of time, you're adding that time to your HttpRequest response time.

I'd advise that you fetch those settings once after login and  then update them only when they change (the settings are updated). This way, you could place the call to `loadSiteSettingsToAppParams` in the `UserIdentity` class and call it after a successful login.

That's just how I'd go about doing this though.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

The easy & nice way to accomplish this by using a comoponent like `SettingComoponent` and place in the components directory `protected/components` then pre load this component in the preload section like this `preload => array('log', 'setting', ...)`. That's it and now you can call this component anywhere you want like `Yii:app()->setting->whatever`.

I hope this is answer can be useful for you.