# How to set a variable when a pages loads in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbie in yii and i want to know whether is there any method which can set a value of a variable whenever any page loads. Eg-(**Its just an example**)  if there is a variable **$count** . Now i want to set the value of the **$count as 3** `whenever any page loads` . I have heard about **onBeginRequest()** but do not know how to do it. ANy help will be appreciated

Comment: beforeRender or beforeAction may help you achieve this i think..

Comment: Is the count variable dynamic or static value ??

Answer (score 1):

In the application life cycle, `onBeginRequest` is `raised right BEFORE the application processes the request`. So you can do anything you want before your pages are loaded.

See this link if you want to know how to use `onBeginRequest`
[How to use events in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410045/how-to-use-events-in-yii)